# How to execute my code to get the wanted result

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I create an array of array that contains objects,

I loop on my array, and for the object that contains y == 5, I affect a boolean variable to the object and then i block the access by a condition,

but I see that the same object on the next array has been affected by the same boolean variable, and my console log displays that the affection is executed only on time,
How to block affecting vaiable to the element of the next array ?

**Code**

```
  test: function(req, res){

    console.log("yesss")
    var a = {x:1}
    let b = {x:2}
    let c = {x:3}
    let d = {x:4}

    let tab1 = []
    a.y = 5
    b.y = 10
    c.y = 10
    d.y = 10
    let group1 = [a, c, d]

    let group2 = [a, b, d]


    tab1.push(group1)
    tab1.push(group2)


    let test = false
    async.each(tab1, function(group, next){

        group.forEach(function(elem){

            if(elem.y == 5 && !test)
            {
                console.log("******* executed ******")
                test = true
                elem.bool = true
            }
            console.log("elem : ", elem)

        })

        next()
    }, function(){

      return res.status(200).json({success: true, data: tab1})
    })
},
```

this is my console log

**Console.log**

```
    ******* executed ******
elem :  { x: 1, y: 5, bool: true }
elem :  { x: 3, y: 10 }
elem :  { x: 4, y: 10 }
elem :  { x: 1, y: 5, bool: true }
elem :  { x: 2, y: 10 }
elem :  { x: 4, y: 10 }
```

**JsonReturn**

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    [
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 5,
            "bool": true
        },
        {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 10
        },
        {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 10
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 5,
            "bool": true
        },
        {
            "x": 2,
            "y": 10
        },
        {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 10
        }
    ]
]
}
```

Comment: I believe it's because the objects in your array are references, and you're adding the same reference to both arrays. try making a deep copy of the object when adding it, and it should differ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i tried to make a deep copy of the referenced object, and it works

```
let group1 = [Object.assign({}, a), c, d]

    let group2 = [Object.assign({}, a), b, d]
```

Answer (score 2):

`group1` and `group2` are arrays referencing the same objects, make a copy using `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` :

```
let group1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([a, c, d]));

let group2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([a, b, d]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Objects are assigned by reference, so you would need to do a deep copy of the object otherwise changes made to one will inevitably alter the other. In your example, you could avoid this by simply defining a new variable to hold the data you want.

In other words, instead of these lines:

```
var a = {x:1}
let b = {x:2}
let c = {x:3}
let d = {x:4}

let tab1 = []
a.y = 5
b.y = 10
c.y = 10
d.y = 10
let group1 = [a, c, d]

let group2 = [a, b, d]
```

You could use these lines:

```
let a = {x:1}
let b = {x:2}
let c = {x:3}
let d = {x:4}
let e = {x:5}
let f = {x:6}

let tab1 = []
a.y = 5
b.y = 10
c.y = 10
d.y = 5
e.y = 10
f.y = 10
let group1 = [a, b, c]

let group2 = [d, e, f]
```

Then you will see that the behavior is as you expect. I'm not sure what the purpose of your code is, but I think you'll know where to go from here.

Comment: thank, yes it's annother purpose of the code that have this problem, so i try to do a deep copy